# replace the string having dynamic character inside square bracket

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a string format:

```
new.ControlField[0] = "";       
new.ControlField[1] = "";
new.ControlField[2] = "";
new.ControlField[3] = "";
```

From the above I need to replace the string format: *new.ControlField[0] =* from every line with empty space. Here the value inside "**[]**" is *dynamic*, so how can I replace it using notepad++ replace feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Notepad++ on my machine, but try searching for

```
new\.ControlField\[\d+\] =
```

and replacing with nothing.  Make sure you have the "grep" or "regex" option selected in your find and replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
Find what:         new\.ControlField\[(\d*)\]\s?=
Replace with:      Just enter space

Search mode:       Regular expression
```

Tested.

Answer (score 0):

/[(\d+)]/

Not sure about notepad++ because I'm on linux and don't have it on my machine but that worked when I tested it at http://www.regexr.com/.